# TypeScript how to use stricter types for a child constructor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, constructor, subclass

Suppose I have two classes, a `Dog` and an `Animal` class. In this example, `Dog extends Animal`.
Now suppose I have two additional classes (one called `Parent`, and another called `Child`). In TypeScript, I am able to type the arguments of my child class's constructor function to be that of my parent class's constructor function's arguments using `ConstructorParameters` like so:

```
class Parent {
  constructor(a: Animal, b: number, c: number) {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Parent>) { // same as parent's arguments: a: Animal, b: number, c: number
    super(...args); // doesn't complain, as args matches the arguments for Parent ([a: Animal, b: number, c: number])
  }
}
```

In this example, `new Child()` and `new Parent()` would accept the same argument types. But how could I type the Child constructor function to accept a stricter type for `a`, such as `Dog`?

```
class Parent {
  constructor(a: Animal, b: number, c: number) {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  //          v----- want to access a in `Child`'s constructor
  constructor(a: Dog, ...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Parent>) {
    super(a, ...args); // <-- complains, I want to pass `a: Dog` and ...args (containing [b: number, c: number])
    a.bark(); // use specific Dog methods (that don't exist on Animal)
  }
}
// Using: 
// - new Child(new Animal(), 0, 0); should complain as Animal is not of type Dog
// - new Child(new Dog(), 0, 0); should work as Dog is of type Dog
```

The above doesn't work, as Child now expects to be passed a `Dog` instance followed by the three arguments for the `Parent` constructor. I was thinking of using `Omit<>`
or `Partial<>` on `ConstructorParameters` to remove the expected `a: Animal` type but couldn't seem to get those to work. I'm also looking for a solution that doesn't involve me needing to pass through the arguments individually to the `super()` call (ie: if I add arguments in Parent's constructor, I won't need to add them to the Child).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how could I type the `Child` constructor function to accept a stricter type for `a`, such as `Dog`?

That sounds like a bad idea, violating the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): one should be able to use `Child` everywhere where `Parent` can be used.

I would therefore recommend generics:

```
class Parent<T extends Animal> {
  constructor(a: T, b: number, c: number) {}
}

class Child extends Parent<Dog> {
  constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Parent<Dog>>) {
    super(...args);
    const a = args[0];
    a.bark(); // use specific Dog methods (that don't exist on Animal)
  }
}
```

Comment: Great point about Liskov's principle. The use of generics here makes a lot of sense - thanks Bergi

Comment: Hi @Bergi, I know its been a few months since you answered this, however, when I try `typeof Parent<Dog>` I'm getting an error, any ideas? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeAjATgUzABcALACgEpNgB7eCakPAOhGoHNSAiReYtPADTQ8ADz6MmkzuQC+MgFChIMACLthIwnngATGAhRpMWMDgDWFKrXoTWHTgHVq1AGbS58xeCjQACqe1CAB4AFQ0tXX0kVBAAPkx5aGgaOkIcAFdgQmocUjAALmgQoSxC+HTkLDwcIWAyiqqcSgwFBS9laABhYkQQHXDtPT8A+GC1NniMROTrNMzs3MkmUzYIQs7ZjKyc-xwwZDwtHAggwgBPAAc8V2H8UaDx2Njm6aSIdKvFyRWIcgBuV4zVLQMDQAC8IJwqwA2gAGAC6AKSSTATBM5gof2gAHpsdB0hA8NAIFdgIgXIhgNBxtADiRqENSCQiNAdLQAOSEDSICBc2hwaJocjTVpAA

Comment: @Shnick Tbh, no - it seems like this construction is not possible with TypeScript :-/ You can only spell out the constructor parameter types, i.e. `...args: [Dog, number, number]` (or the same with three named parameters). Would make a great new question though how to instantiate the type of the constructor of a generic class.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, appreciate you taking another look at this. I'm logging off now, but I might try and put together another question about this in the next few days or so (I would need some time to work out the best way to ask the question, as my typescript vocab/knowledge is a bit rusty).

Comment: Hi @Bergi, thought I might update you - I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71438203/11158354) question and it looks like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58338814/11158354) is a possible work around to this TypeScript limitation.

Answer (score 1):

try conditional types

```
type RestWithoutOne<K> = K extends [infer WithThis, ...infer WithRest] ? WithRest : never;

class Child extends Parent {
  //          v----- want to access a in `Child`'s constructor
  constructor(a: Dog, ...args: RestWithoutOne<ConstructorParameters<typeof Parent>>) {
    const a = args[0];
    super(a, ...args); // <-- complains, I want to pass `a: Dog` and ...args (containing [b: number, c: number])
    a.bark(); // use specific Dog methods (that don't exist on Animal)
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeBfAUKSMAIgPYDm0ApgB4AuF8AJjAimpjtNAA4CuARiETBofMACcA1gAoAlBg6dowYvAjEQFAHQgyUgOSjJemQtxYA3Div4o0AArj6Ndp2WqaYnsBrExUsABccEioIAA0IkHwPMh8FGIRwFExcWIymGZWNACeXBT2jvA0sGKkMAC80ADCKhAeXj5iDmJgyBR0YhAAPDl5xABmBWJOAHyWvfkAShR1AOqINAAWxDw0APLwFF0A0iPQlduUtPRM0ADaiPD98dDzSwAqi4gQEZpvl9ditwuL03UAutAAPzfJZ-ZxRCgAN3ilms4FsVSeIAYRzojBgzScLmgAHpcYpCYooQBaMlk6AAdzARWgPmgYGAwBmMDA0Eu0AABkjECjOXoYG46p5vL4FEL6qK-IFoCRSK83uIykFwXdlqsNlsau4RY1mq12vFuhMBkNRiN0vJCRKGfsGaUIGcAAz-SyEiA8PLShWaJUQGTmPEEroU5TILjgS4vaAASSpNOc9K4BC5MrlnIZjGgb19DugUjcNDAl0u5DOfGSsXiiUrqX+JkJYE0hmkAaD0B4EHyEDywEQ-SEsrI0DaS2IpykSzAzgYKj0zmoz2cKmCrBADegmXx0AAqhBS0EcJtKdVkQwpMfV6FZBEnbe2-iIOqUUpiOHI-AGcwQmxntB4MQy6DBMQ6kEeFAnjyKIXhBoE3tAd4IQ+uJPisL6Ur4EhfqB7IwKaIFykAA)

Comment: Wow, this looks great Mike. I wasn't aware you could write such sophisticated types like that. Thanks a bunch